# Supabase function work only when added in dbms, but not through query

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

I have two tables, `feedback` and `quests`.

`feedback` table:

```
create table
  public.feedback (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    user_id uuid null,
    quest bigint null,
    comment text null,
    rating numeric null,
    constraint feedback_pkey primary key (id),
    constraint feedback_quest_fkey foreign key (quest) references quests (id) on delete cascade,
    constraint feedback_user_id_fkey foreign key (user_id) references profile (id) on delete cascade
  ) tablespace pg_default;

create trigger update_quest_data_on_feedback before insert on feedback for each row
execute function update_quest_data ();

create trigger insert_feedback_duplicate before insert on feedback for each row
execute function check_duplicate_feedback ();
```

`quests` table:

```
create table
  public.quests (
    id bigint generated by default as identity,
    name text null,
    description text null,
    city text null,
    cover text null,
    created_at timestamp with time zone not null default now(),
    price numeric null,
    total_reviews numeric null,
    total_score numeric null,
    rating numeric(5, 2) null,
    duration numeric null,
    players text null,
    constraint quests_pkey primary key (id)
  ) tablespace pg_default;
```

And I have a trigger on table `feedback` on `INSERT`, before event, for each row. That trigger fires function:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE quests
  SET total_reviews = total_reviews + 1,
      total_score = total_score + NEW.rating
  WHERE id = NEW.quest;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Function returns trigger.

That means, that every time I add a new row to `feedback`, function must update `quests` data, `total_reviews` must be +1 and `total_score` must be `total_score` + `NEW.rating`(This is the rating, that user sends), where id equals NEW.quest.

But there is a problem. If I add new row to `feedback` via JS query on client-side when user  send the feedback, supabase add the row to `feedback`, but don't update the quest rating, but if I add a new row to `feedback` via supabase site, by my own, supabase add the new row to `feedback` AND update the quest rating. I have no idea why, please help.

Comment: I'd make sure the quest record exists when you add a feedback in your JS code. Also I see `feedback.quest` is allowed to be null. Are you sure you pass the quest ID to your insert statement?

Comment: I guess the quest ID is passed, because when you add it through supabase site it works. I'll make `feedback.quest` not null and check passed values types, then paste a comment here.

Answer (score 0):

The solve of this issue is add `UPDATE` RLS Policy to table `quests`. I just forgot about it.

When you add a new row to `feedback` update function is working, cuz it triggered with admin privs. But when you triggers this function via JS you don't have admin privs, that's why you can insert new row to `feedback`, but can't update the `quests`